# Adding Summary Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, session-variables

I have an asp.net website with two forms. The first form contains input controls for a user to enter shipping information. The second form contains summary information. The problem I have is that when a user adds an item by pressing the `addButton` on the first form, they should be able to enter another item and the sum of the price of those items should be passed to the summary form, instead it just passes the price of the most current item entered after `addButton` is clicked. I'm just beginning asp.net so any help would be appreciated.

```
protected void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dollA = new List<decimal>();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        weightInteger = int.Parse(weightTextBox.Text);
        quantityInteger = int.Parse(quanTextBox.Text);
        priceDecimal = decimal.Parse(priceTextBox.Text);

        // Calculate the current item price.
        currentPriceDecimal = priceDecimal * quantityInteger;
        // Format and display the current item price.
        currentTextBox.Text = currentPriceDecimal.ToString("C");

        // Calculate the dollar amount due.
        dollarAmountDecimal += currentPriceDecimal;

        dollA.Add(dollarAmountDecimal);
        dollDec = dollA.Sum();
        Session["Amount"] = dollDec;
    }
}
```

Summary Form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount;

    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Amount"]);

    amountTextBox.Text = amount.ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: Why is there a loop that processes the same input fields repeatedly? you could try `Session["Amount"] += dollDec;` and see what happens. Your session variable is getting overwritten in this method and I don't think it has scope of your other inputs currently.

Comment: I got rid of the for loop and tried `Session["Amount"] += dollDec;` but it bring an error that says 'Operator += cannot be applied to operands of type object and decimal' @dukedukes

Comment: In that case do `Session["Amount"] = (decimal)Session["Amount"] + dollDec;`

Comment: It brings the error 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object' and points to the `Session["Amount"] = (decimal)Session["Amount"] + dollDec;` @dukedukes

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth. Do a null check before the loop and give it an initial value like so: `if (Session["Amount"] == null) Session["Amount"] = 0;`

Comment: You may need to assign it to `Decimal.Zero` if the 0 is interpreted as an `int`

Comment: Yes that worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you so much! @dukedukes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for the OP based on the comments.

```
protected void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Amount"] == null)
        Session["Amount"] = Decimal.Zero;

    weightInteger = int.Parse(weightTextBox.Text);
    quantityInteger = int.Parse(quanTextBox.Text);
    priceDecimal = decimal.Parse(priceTextBox.Text);

    // Calculate the current item price.
    currentPriceDecimal = priceDecimal * quantityInteger;
    // Format and display the current item price.
    currentTextBox.Text = currentPriceDecimal.ToString("C");

    // Calculate the dollar amount due.
    dollarAmountDecimal += currentPriceDecimal;

    Session["Amount"] = (decimal)Session["Amount"] + dollarAmountDecimal;
}
```